# Property 'ResultJson' does not exist on type 'Book[]'

Tags: json, angular, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

I am using angular 4 and getting this error when i am running ng build --prod. Its not giving any error on running ng-serve and works fine. ResultJson is my JSON file. If i remove ResultJson, it doesn't show any data on UI. Help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my html file.

```
<div *ngIf="books?.ResultJson.length === 0">
    <h4>no result found</h4>
</div>

<div *ngIf="books?.ResultJson.length > 0">
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Name</h4></td>
                <td><h4>Id</h4></td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let b of book?.ResultJson">
                <td>{{p.name}}</td>
                <td>{{p.id}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

this is the array in my typescript file

```
books: Book[] = [];
```

Comment: books is an array you should call one item of book:
```*ngIf="books[o]?.ResultJson.length === 0"```

Comment: Tried but it says the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the problem with AOT. Instead of **ng-build --prod**, if i run **ng build --prod --aot false** it works fine. Don't know what is the exact solution but it made my code work fine.

Comment: AoT is for generating more efficient js code (e.g. templates are generated no at run, but at compilation time). So in this approach you loose it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with question mark: >`?`<  Do not use `*ngIf="books?.Resu...` instead use `*ngIf="books && books.ResultJson.length > 0"` or create method `booksExists()` which return true/false for `if` (the same for `book`).  This is probably connected with AoT (Ahead of Time - probably used in production compilation) - i found this information in [this angular-framework](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter#aot-donts).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am not using books?.id and as i am new to angular 4 not sure how can i do this.

Comment: Thanks for the link +1.

Comment: this *ngIf="books && books.ResultJson.length > 0" didnt work, but i created one method and its working.